# How to redirect / link variables in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, variables, echo

I am trying to linking variables in a bash script (three or more). For example:

```
read -e -p "Enter the 5' restriction enzyme:" RE5
```

I expect that the user enter "BamHI", and I would like to link the user input (BamHI) to another text string, ("GGATCC"). But I don't know if all user will input it as lower or upper case, so to correct it I use:

```
RE5l=`echo "$RE5" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`
```

And set:

```
bamhi=GGATCC
```

Now when I enter `echo $RE5l` I get `bamhi` , but I would like to get `GGATCC`

But I don't know how to do it or what is wrong. All suggestions, correction or another way to do it are very welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "link the user input"?  Under what circumstances?

Comment: BashFAQ #6 is directly on-point: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The answer by @gniourf_gniourf](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26195063/14122) is better practice, and is what you should accept and use. This is being provided only because it's a more direct answer to the question.

Almost everything you're doing is fine:

```
read -e -p "Enter the 5' restriction enzyme:" RE5
RE5l=${RE5,,}
bamhi=GGATCC
```

...but if you want to honor indirection in the lookup, use a `!` character to do so:

```
echo "${!RE5l}"
```

...instead of

```
echo "${RE5l}"
```

Comment: Thanks @Charles Duffy and @gniourf_gniourf by the answers. The `echo "${!RE5l}"` did the correct job. Now, when I enter `echo "${!RE5l}"` I get `GGATCC`. But the database solution looks also interesting, as I am basic level user I will check it later... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Better to put your "database" in an associative array:
declare -A database
database[bamhi]=GGATCC

read -rep "Enter the 5' restriction enzyme: " RE5

# Bash has builtin operator for lowercase conversion
RE5l=${RE5,,}

# Now you can retrieve the value from the associative array:
printf 'Output: %s\n' "${database[$RE5l]}"
```

If you want to check for existence in the database, replace the last two lines with:

```
# Checking whether data is in database
# If exists, retrieve the value from the associative array
if [[ -z ${database[$RE5l]+1} ]]; then
    echo "Not found"
else
    printf 'Output: %s\n' "${database[$RE5l]}"
fi
```